# DBLink to connect to remote RDS Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I am trying connect to remote RDS PostgreSQL database from another RDS PostgreSQL [both SSH Enabled] and getting errors. Could anyone please help me to establish the connection in the correct way.

SELECT dblink_connect
('myconn', 'dbname=Test-Prod port=5432 host=10.60.0.10 user=postgres password=abcd');

ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  could not connect to server: Connection timed out
Is the server running on host "10.60.0.10" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
SQL state: 08001

SELECT dblink_connect
('myconn', 'dbname=Test-Prod host=10.60.0.10 user=postgres password=abcd sslmode=require ss_host=10.20.2.12 ssh_port=22 ssh_user=ubuntu ssh_password=acbde');

ERROR:  password is required
DETAIL:  Non-superusers must provide a password in the connection string.
SQL state: 2F003

I'd be very grateful if you have any other option to help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: 1) *... Connection timed out ...* indicates to me that you have not opened port 5432 in the firewall. 2) Not sure what this *ss_host=10.20.2.12 ssh_port=22 ssh_user=ubuntu ssh_password=acbde* is supposed to be doing?

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I will check with my network team. Do we need to use SSL_mode in the connection string?

Comment: 1) ssl_mode is between the Postgres client and the Postgres server. You are not going to get to that until you can get to port 5432 and it really has nothing to do with SSH connections over port 22. 2) What you do with ssl_mode is going to be determined by how you set up SSL on the server per [SSL support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssl-tcp.html).

Answer (score 0):

Establish an ssh tunnel on your own, and then use dblink to connect through it.  dblink has no provision of establishing a tunnel for you.

Something like:

```
ssh -L 9999:10.60.0.10:5432 ubuntu@10.20.2.12
```

Then you would edit your dblink connection string to point to the local end of the tunnel, '... host=localhost port=9999 ...'

Your first attempt is blocked by a firewall.  Which makes sense, as there is no point in having an ssh tunnel if you just let people bypass it.

Your second attempt fails because you specified made-up parameters in your connection string.  dblink reports this as a password problem even though it is not.  I think that has been reported as a bug before, but I can't find the bug report and evidently it has not been fixed.